# Copying and closing folds in Vim

Tags: vim, folding

Despite using Vim for a decade, sometimes I still struggle with folding. Everything in this question is reproducible with no .vimrc in Vim 7.3. I am using foldmethod=marker with default foldmarkers.

Consider the following nested fold structure (using foldmethod=marker and default markers). The first column is the line number (fold0 has zero indent).

```
 1|{{{ fold0
 2|    {{{ fold1
 3|        {{{ fold2
 4|        }}}
 5|    }}}
 6|}}}
```

Suppose `fold1` and `fold2` are both closed and the cursor is on line 2. I can yank and put the closed fold using `yyp`, but the newly inserted folds are all open.

What I would like is for folds resulting from a "put" command to be closed. Alternatively, is there a convenient way to close them after the "put"? That is, from this position (with the cursor on line 6):

```
 1|{{{ fold0
 2|+---  4 lines: fold1----------------------------------------
 6|    {{{ fold3
 7|        {{{ fold4
 8|        }}}
 9|    }}}
10|}}}
```

I can use `zc` to close fold3, but fold 4 remains open after `zo`. If instead I use `zC`, it closes fold3 and fold 0, but fold 4 is still open when I do `2zo`. This is not how I would expect recursive fold-closing to work. Is there a way to achieve `zc` but also recursively closing all contained folds?

The company I work for specifies that folds are defined by matching pairs without an explicit foldlevel, so solutions involving explicit foldlevel are of no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sequence (after your <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>) seems to do what you want:

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> - visually select from the `{` under the cursor to the corresponding `}`

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> - close all folds under the cursor recursively (unfortunately, this includes the outer folds that you want to remain open)

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - open just enough folds to display the cursor line

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> - close the single outer fold of the new material

Of course, you'd want to map this to some other key combination in your vimrc.

Comment: This a very good solution, but I find the screen flashing due to the visual selection rather distracting.

Comment: If you feel strongly about this you could turn off the highlighting first (`hi Visual ...`) and turn it back on again afterwards. But that's probably more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Excellent! It will take some tweaking to work in every case, but you have certainly solved the issue. Thanks.